# MySQL Grouping Survey Ratings

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have 2 tables

```
survey_question: id | question
```

AND

```
survey_answer: question_id | answer
```

answer is just a number 1-5

I need to group the results by question_id

something like questionid:arrayofanswers,questionid:arrayofanswers,etc

Here's what I have right now

```
SELECT a.answer,a.question_id
FROM survey_answer AS a
GROUP BY a.question_id
```

I was originally joining survey_question in there to get the question field as a label, but I just want this to work for now.

What am I missing?

Extra points if you can throw in the answer average for each question as well :)

UPDATE:

I'm getting closer with this:

```
SELECT q.question,a.answer
FROM survey_answer AS a
JOIN survey_question AS q ON a.question_id=q.id
ORDER BY a.question_id
```

but still not sure how to group them together the way I want

Comment: we don't know what you want.

Comment: I was attempting to use phpmyadmin to create a csv file where I have the questions as the columns and the answers as rows, but I think I'll just use php instead

Comment: I think GROUP_CONCAT() function might help you. and maybe the AVG() function for average.